# How to print the numbers 1 to n that are not divisible by x or y?

Tags: java

```
public static void notDivisible(int n, int x, int y)
{
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("These are the ints from 1 to" + n + "that are not divisible by" + x + "or" + y);
    n = kb.nextInt();
    x = kb.nextInt();
    y = kb.nextInt();
    if((n%x) == 0)
    {

    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println()
    }
    if((n%y) == 0)
    {

    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println();
    }
```

So this is all I have so far. I know that I have to use modulus and print out the numbers that aren't divisible by the number, but how can I do it?

Comment: Ask a SPECIFIC question.  We're not here to do your homework.

Comment: You get `n`, `x`, and `y` values as arguments, and print a message with them, but then you throw them away and get new values from `System.in` to actually work with...

Answer (score 0):

Make a loop from 1 to the limit (n).

```
for(int i = 1; i < n; i++)
{
    if(i % x != 0 || i % y != 0)
    {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

The modulus (%) is the rest of the division. If i % x is different from 0 that means i cannot be divided by x.

Comment: Add some explanation of what this code does and how it works.

Comment: You may also want to say `!=0` rather than `>0`. Technically moduli may be negative, even if it does not happen often.

Answer (score 0):

This reeks of homework.  But against my better judgment:

```
for(int z=1; z<n; z++) { // Test all numbers from 1 to n
    if((z % x) == 0) { 
       System.out.println(z + " is divisible by " + x);
    } else System.out.println(z + " isn't divisible by " + x); 

    if((z % y) == 0) { 
       System.out.println(z + " is divisible by " + y);
    } else System.out.println(z + " isn't divisible by " + y); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you will need to ask the user the numbers `n`, `x` and `y` before printing them.

Then what you want to achieve is a typical job for `for` loops:

```
for(int i=0; i<n; ++i) {
    if(i%x != 0 && i%y != 0) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

Try doing your next exercise alone ;)

Comment: actually he wants to print the not divisible , u did the opposite

Answer (score 0):

Reading "not divisible by x or y" as "divisible by neither x nor y":

```
for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
    if (i%x!=0 && i%y!=0) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```